# Using anime character image as wallpaper with intention of motivation

Tags: halal-haram, image

Assalamu alikum.
I have a doubt regarding using images. I would like to know if using an anime character's image as wallpaper with intention to get Motivated with my workout.
I kind of feel i should work hard when i see a specific anime character.
Will it be haram or is it allowed?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Pictures, images or videos (including of anime characters) are not haram, except if the content of the image is haram, like nudity o sexual pictures or something like that.

I have pictures of my parents in phones to motivate me, picture of a car as wallpaper for my laptop, it is allowed.

Comment: But there is a hadeed stating prophet (s.a) asked ayisha (a.s) to remove a sheet with picture of a bird. so there are some issues, right?

Comment: But at that time idols were very popular and a picture was able to lead to worshipping idols.

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha can you please quote the hadith. I heard of our prophet (saw) being mad about the fact that Aisha (RA) had a curtain with portraits

Answer (score 1):

Ali (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: "Shall I not send you on the same mission as the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) sent me? Do not leave any built-up tomb without levelling it, and do not leave any picture in any house without erasing it." (Reported by Muslim and al-Nisaa'i; this is the version narrated by al-Nisaa'i).

Ibn 'Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him and his father) reported that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "Every image-maker will be in the Fire, and for every image that he made a soul will be created for him, which will be punished in the Fire." Ibn 'Abbaas said: "If you must do that, make pictures of trees and other inanimate objects." (Reported by Muslim, 3/1871)

I’ve read that some of the contemporary scholars allowed people to take photographs on mobile phones or any other digital devices without printing them. Besides, if drawings or pictures of animated things doesn’t resemble real people, like in some cartoons, such pictures are not considered as prohibited images. With regards to your question of anime character as an inspiration, I don’t know.